# Best approach to access and modify video and audio streams of an OBS user

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, rtmp, obs

I'm working on a project where I need to access and modify the video and audio streams of an OBS user in real-time.

Currently, I have set up a system where the OBS user sends their stream to an RTMP server. From there, I access the frames and process them as needed. However, I can't help but think that this is an inefficient way to achieve my goal.

Is there a better approach to directly access the video and audio streams of an OBS user without relying on an RTMP server? I would like to find a more direct and efficient method for real-time stream manipulation.

Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. My primary programming language is Python, but I'm open to exploring other options if they provide a more elegant solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more specifics about your project, there are a few possible options:

## NDI

[NDI](https://ndi.video/) is a protocol for low latency realtime video over high bandwidth networks, like LANs.  There is an [NDI plugin](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-ndi-newtek-ndi%E2%84%A2-integration-into-obs-studio.528/) for OBS.  If you implement your solution with NDI, then it will work with all the other software beyond just OBS.

## OBS Plugin

You can make your own [OBS plugin](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-plugintemplate).

## Custom Output with FFmpeg

Using recording options under advanced, you can set a custom command line for FFmpeg.  From there, you can send your video elsewhere if you want.